# Resizing image with PHP or CSS?

Tags: php, html, css

Basically I have a `div` which contains a user's photo.
In order for the photo to fill the div completely, I must resize the photo.

- The thing is, I am relatively new to programming and I am not sure which approach is most appropriate to resize the image to fit the div (I'm guessing the most robust way is PHP).

**My question is:** Should I resize the image using a PHP function, or should I be setting specified photo dimensions with CSS?  (Looking for most robust method)

Comment: css just changes the DISPLAY SIZE of an image. the entirety of the jpg/png/whatever is still transferred server->client, so if you're doing this resizing to save bandwidth, well... that won't help.

Comment: Does the size of the div change?   I assume a user uploads the image?  I'd suggesting looking at something like Boostrap and how it handles making images "responsive".  That can give you some ideas on the CSS approaches.  That works best for down-sizing, less so when it comes to up-sizing because of the impact on image quality.

Comment: It depends on what it is you want to do.  If you want to affect the display, CSS is fine, however if you want to change it on upload, you may wish to install Imagick

Comment: I am not concerned with actual file size, just specified dimensions to be displayed to the user.

Comment: Before the user upload their picture you can check the size, width, height... just to make sure you have and standard size for user's avatar/pic, if document(images) weight is not a concern then just use plain CSS...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see how StackOverflow does it, simply setting a width and height on the image. What you are thinking of when describing using CSS...

[image]

```
<img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/6bc2ad4c62572ad8df0b54d91e17617f?s=48&amp;d=identicon&amp;r=PG" alt="" width="24" height="24" class="avatar-me js-avatar-me">
```

Now that works great for down-sizing, less so for image up-sizing.  Get the user to upload something equal in size of larger than the maximum size you will display at.  Otherwise you will get "stretched" poor quality.

```html
<img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/6bc2ad4c62572ad8df0b54d91e17617f?s=48&amp;d=identicon&amp;r=PG" alt="" width="324" height="324" class="avatar-me js-avatar-me">
```

Then of course aspect ratio is the other factor.

Comment: If I resized using Imagick instead of CSS, would this prevent the stretching of the image as it changes the actual file itself and not the display?

Comment: No.  You can cheat a bit and do an effect like blur or other algorithms to tweak it, fractal interpolation etc.., but you can't "zoom and enhance" like they do on CSI :)  You can't turn a 100x100 pixel image into a 200x200 pixel image without a loss.

Comment: Awesome. I will be using CSS as I am not concerned with file size :)

Comment: Might be worth a read: http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-resize-and-make-images-larger-without-losing-quality/

Comment: Hmm, the article you linked actually helped me understand and grasp the concept of Bitmap images, which I never knew before :-) Too bad there isn't a way to to make enlarged images somewhat clearer, whilst using CSS :(. However, I may use the function `getimagesize()` to retrieve the height and width, this way I can set dimension limits on file upload (example: setting dimensions close of that to my div), so when the image is resized in CSS, it will atleast meet a standard of quality, in contrast to not setting a limit on dimensions, causing images to stretch greatly in some cases.

Comment: I learn something new on here everyday.  Sounds like you're making progress.  Good luck with the project.

Comment: This works just for square photos. Sometimes what users select as their avatars maybe have different width and height. We need to crop or resize it first as considered size. How can I do that?

Comment: @Shafizadeh There are JS libs out there that can help with the selection and cropping.  Can force a given aspect ratio etc.  Suggest asking a new question as this one is "closed".

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely resize using CSS. You could resize with a PHP function, however you most likely will have to resize the image, save its resized copy, then serve it to the end user. In CSS you'll just be scaling the image's display size on the user-side without modifying the image itself.

Answer (score 0):

You mention that you're new to programming. For this reason, I'd look at Bootstrap as a framework. You do this by adding Bootstrap's CSS file that you download from their page into your CSS file directory and linking to it in your HTML header.

You can make use of Bootstrap's grid system to ensure the image takes up the full span of the `div`:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
```

You can also make use of the img-responsive class so that it handles the images display responsively:

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="images/sample.png">
```

If the concern is more to the tune of image quality as it stretches to fill the `div` completely, the easiest solution is to request a higher resolution image from the user to work with.