# How to resize image yii2 when uploading

Tags: yii, yii2

This is my post controller function. I always upload images less then `200x200`, and those images are stored in the *'upload'* folder. After uploading the image, the id number is changed to something like `4546464.png`. But I want to change the image size to `60x60` when uploading and store it after changing the size and quality to `60x60x30`. This code uploads fine but not changing size and quality.

```
public function actionCreate() {
    $model = new Monitor();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        if ($model->payment_processor) {
            $model->payment_processor = implode(',', $model>payment_processor);
        }

        $model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file');

        if ($model->file != '') {
            $model->image = time() . '.' . $model->file->extension;
        }

        $model->update_at = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
        $model->save();

        if ($model->file != '') {             
            $model->file->saveAs('upload/' . $model->image);               
        }
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', ['model' => $model]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you try something? if this code work how we can help you? for example you can use some php function, try to search on google and you will find some tutorials.

Comment: I have searched Google, but I do not know better about yii2. I need exactly code which will work with my code perfectly that can i do by myself. Thanks for your lines @Eric

Comment: check it out my answer ! it's works 100%

Comment: see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32148467/resizing-image-with-php-or-css) to decide if you still want to go with `server-side` processing for image resizing.

Answer (score 0):

, you have to first upload the image in your server then resize it to what size you want , another way   is before you

```
 $model->file->saveAs('upload/' . $model->image);
```

resize it , but i recommend to you save the Original  file and then resize it as a copy.

here is function to resize and crop image from center :

```
public static function resize_crop_image($max_width, $max_height, $source_file, $dst_dir, $quality = 100){
    $quality = 10;
    $imgsize = getimagesize($source_file);
    $width = $imgsize[0];
    $height = $imgsize[1];
    $mime = $imgsize['mime'];

    switch($mime){
        case 'image/gif':
            $image_create = "imagecreatefromgif";
            $image = "imagegif";
            break;

        case 'image/png':
            $image_create = "imagecreatefrompng";
            $image = "imagepng";
            $quality = 9;
            break;

        case 'image/jpeg':
            $image_create = "imagecreatefromjpeg";
            $image = "imagejpeg";
            $quality = 100;
            break;



        default:
            return false;
            break;
    }

    $dst_img = imagecreatetruecolor($max_width, $max_height);
    $src_img = $image_create($source_file);

    $width_new = $height * $max_width / $max_height;
    $height_new = $width * $max_height / $max_width;
    //if the new width is greater than the actual width of the image, then the height is too large and the rest cut off, or vice versa
    if($width_new > $width){
        //cut point by height
        $h_point = (($height - $height_new) / 2);
        //copy image
        imagecopyresampled($dst_img, $src_img, 0, 0, 0, $h_point, $max_width, $max_height, $width, $height_new);
    }else{
        //cut point by width
        $w_point = (($width - $width_new) / 2);
        imagecopyresampled($dst_img, $src_img, 0, 0, $w_point, 0, $max_width, $max_height, $width_new, $height);
    }

    $image($dst_img, $dst_dir, $quality);

    if($dst_img)imagedestroy($dst_img);
    if($src_img)imagedestroy($src_img);
}
```

use this function as easy you can :

```
yourModel::resize_crop_image(150,150, $path, 'upload/'.$name_you_want_or_random_string.'.jpg',$q);
```

the $path is a path of the original file that uploaded .
you have to create a upload folder in your web app directory or change destination to  where you want .

Answer (score 0):

I am using the [imageprocessor](https://github.com/phtamas/yii2-imageprocessor) extension and I'm very happy with it. You just have to add confgurations to the imageprocessor component and on save you have to call the save method of the component. It will create a new image with the size you've configured. It has a nice documentation. Give it a try.